What is the bracket rule for removing letters in quotations?
Consider the text:

She screams and throws teddy bears into the Internet.

Suppose I write, "I understand screaming, but what does it mean to 'throw teddy bears into the Internet'?", with "throw teddy bears into the Internet" being a direct quotation.
Note that I've modified the tense of "throw" by removing the 's'. Typically, modifications to tense are handled by enclosing the added/amended content in square brackets, but in this instance (and various others) there is no added content.
The three options that come to mind are:

not using any brackets at all
using empty square brackets, i.e., "throw[] teddy bears into the Internet"
enclosing the entire word in square brackets, i.e., "[throw] teddy bears into the Internet"

Unfortunately, (1) gives no indication that the quotation has been altered, (2) looks unusual and might confuse readers, and (3) erroneously implies that I've changed the entire verb rather than just its tense.
Note that cases also exist where the removed letter isn't at the end of the word. For example, given the text, "The stupid-looking dice were cast on the table," and text explaining, "A 'stupid-looking die' is one with seven sides," the direct quotation of "stupid-looking dice" eliminates the 'c' from 'dice'.
I've perused a number of online writing guides and haven't found one that addresses this issue specifically. Is it covered by any official style guides? What is the best practice?

Are you using any particular style guide? Most will tell you that you don't need to quote everything and paraphrase is often preferred. I have no way of knowing what is the reason for quoting those lines, but you might for instance just put "teddy bears" or "stupid-looking" into quotation marks if the exact words are important, but paraphrase the rest. Otherwise probably 3; I'm sure if you search you can find similar examples.

"I understand screaming, but what does it mean to 'throw teddy bears into the Internet'?" is not-the-best grammar. It should be: "I understand screaming, but what does "throws teddy bears into the Internet" mean? The quote marks can be BrE or AmE style.

@StuartF - I realize that paraphrasing is always an option. I was just wondering if it's the only option in this case. In the piece of writing that inspired me to ask this question, I've consistently quoted bits and pieces of a source text without paraphrasing (mainly due to the sensitive nature of the quotations) and I was hoping to avoid it entirely. I can certainly reword to avoid having to change the tense, as Lambie suggests, but it seems odd to me that a language as versatile as English would force a change in tense due to a lack of mechanics. Ah well. Thanks for your response.

As Lambie alluded to, what does it mean to... doesn’t sound like native English. I understand screaming, but what does “[she] throws teddy bears into the Internet” mean?

If you want to preserve the overall order you could use "I understand screaming, but what is meant by 'throws teddy bears into the Internet'"?

The Chicago Manual of Style, sixteenth edition (2010) argues against tinkering with verb tenses to get a quoted passage to align with the grammar and syntax of the surrounding narrative. According to Chicago, writers should take the opposite tack, accommodating the surrounding narrative to the grammar and syntax of the quotation.
Chapter 13 of Chicago, titled "Quotations and Dialogue" contains a primary subsection titled "Quotations in Relation to Text," and that subsection contains a secondary subsection titled "Assimilation into Surrounding Text." Here are the two guidelines that appear beneath that secondary subhead:

13.11 Logical and grammatical assimilation. In incorporating fragmentary quotations into a text, phrase the surrounding sentence in such a way that the quoted words fit into logically and grammatically, quoting only as much of the original as is necessary. [Example omitted.]
13.12 Integrating tenses and pronouns. In quoting verbatim writers need to integrate tenses and pronouns into the new context. [Example omitted.]
Occasional adjustments to the original may be bracketed. This device should be used sparingly, however.

[Example:] Mr. Graham has resolutely ducked the issue, saying he won't play the game of rumormongering, even though he has "learned from {his} mistakes."


In the example above, Mr. Graham undoubtedly originally said "I have [or I've] learned from my mistakes." In such a case, swapping in "[his]" for "my" can hardly lead to any misunderstanding. But what if the writer quoting Mr. Graham had tried to include even more of the original sentence in the quotation? Doing so might have resulted in a construction like this:

Mr. Graham has resolutely ducked the issue, saying he won't play the game of rumormongering, even though he asserts that "[he] ha[s] learned from [his] mistakes."

It's not that readers can't figure out the original sentence by replacing all of the bracketed words with their probable source words—it's that readers shouldn't have to. Any imagined fidelity to accuracy that might result from retaining as much of the original wording as possible within the quotation is outweighed by the burden of sleuthing out each underlying term. At some point, you have to wonder why the writer didn't simply frame the sentence along these lines:

Mr. Graham has resolutely ducked the issue, saying he won't play the game of rumormongering, even though, as he also asserts, "I have learned from my mistakes."

The particular type of tinkering that the posted question deals with is considerably more problematic than changing "my" to "[his]" in Chicago's example—or, for that matter, than changing "know" to "know[s]" in the following example:

[Original statement by Mr. Murkle:] I know what's going on around here.
[Quotation as rendered in a newspaper article:] Mr. Murkle then stood up and declared to the others at the table that he "know[s] what's going on around here."

In this instance, at least we can see the nature of the alteration that has occurred: some form of "know" has become "knows." But in the case that the posted question asks about, the actual alteration consists of the removal of a letter. The poster suggests three options for handling that situation:


not using any brackets at all
using empty square brackets, i.e., "throw[] teddy bears into the Internet"
enclosing the entire word in square brackets, i.e., "[throw] teddy bears into the Internet"


None of these is satisfactory under Chicago's guidelines. Option #1 amounts to a silent alteration of the original quotation—an action that Chicago considers improper outside a few narrowly defined exceptional cases (such as omitting the final period in a quotation or changing it to a comma "as required"). Option #2 doesn't tell readers anything except, maybe, that some unidentified change has occurred. Option #3 introduces a new problem: readers have no way of knowing whether the whole word in brackets ("[throw]") is replacing another form the same verb or replacing a completely different verb or filling a void where there was originally no verb at all.
A fourth option might be to introduce the omitted letter in brackets as a struckthrough letter:

I understand "screaming," but what does it mean to "throw[s] teddy bears into the Internet"?

But this option isn't great either, for several reasons. First, it isn't an established editorial style convention (as far as I know), so readers would still have to figure out fore themselves why the bracketed addition was there. Second, the strikethrough isn't particularly obvious when applied to a single letter such as s, so readers might not even recognize the typographical character for what it is. Third, and most critically, it creates an interruption in the flow of the text for no reason other than that the writer didn't take the time to work out a way to frame the sentence that didn't put the surrounding text at grammatical odds with the quoted wording.
There are two basic ways to recast the sentence to avoid the need for any of the bracketed interpolation options discussed above.
Option A: Abandon the attempt to include the wording as a direct quotation. For example:

I understand screaming, but what does it mean to throw teddy bears into the Internet?

Option B: Accommodate the original wording by revising the introductory wording. For example:

I understand "she screams," but what does it mean to say that she "throws teddy bears into the Internet"?

or:

I understand screaming, but what does "throws teddy bears into the Internet" mean?

Interestingly, the poster's original example already includes an instance of paraphrasing: the sentence begins "I understand screaming"—not "I understand 'screams'" or "I understand 'scream[ing]'"—so punctilious adherence to the original wording is already off the table. Under the circumstances, I don't think it makes sense to me to try to use bracketed interpolations here at all.
More generally, the problem with the poster's proposed use of brackets to indicate omission of one or more letters in a word is that conventional editorial use of brackets is to signal the introduction of inserted content within a quotation—not to signal the removal of original content. That conventional use makes it more likely that readers would simply be baffled by seeing a pair of empty brackets parked at the end of a word, as in the case of "throw[]." Consequently, probably the best short answer to the question posed in the title to the question above—"What is the bracket rule for removing letters in a quotation?" is "Don't use brackets to remove letters in a quotation."
